# How to put any widget behind a bottom navigation bar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to put a text or container behind bottom Navigation Bar like pinterest bottom navigation

**Container behind bottom navigation bar**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Container(
      height: 1000,
      width: 200,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code snippet, what have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This question needs some code to help us reproduce the problem. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this. I also recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `Scaffold`:

```
extendBody: true,
```

Comment: I already added this but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Try add this: `bottomNavigationBar: new Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          
          canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar())`